# python map data to list of lists/tuples

Tags: python, list, numpy, list-comprehension

I have a list of 3D points which I'm trying to map to a list as below:

```
plot = map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2], voxelGrid[x]), data)
```

That doesn't do what I want.
The intentions is for `plot[0]` to hold all the values from the first index of data, `plot[1]` to hold all the values from the second index and so on.

I can do this really inefficiently by performing a list comprehension for each different value I'm trying to group, but I feel there is a nicer way.

**Data**

```
data = [(35, 35, 32), (35, 36, 33), (35, 38, 34)...] # xyz points
```

voxelGrid is a 3D numpy array that contains a value at each of the points above.

I'm trying to get this output:

`plot = [(35,35,35),(35,36,38), (32,33,34), (voxelGrid[first point], voxelGrid[second point], voxelGrid[third point])]`

Comment: `plot = zip(*data)` may be.

Comment: im also trying to add in the fourth element which is  an intensity value at the `xyz` location

Comment: Are you using NumPy? Please provide some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `zip(*)` with a `tuple()` and generator expression:

```
zip(*data) + [tuple(voxelGrid[x] for x in data)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you want like this??

```
>>> data = [(35, 35, 32), (35, 36, 33), (35, 38, 34)]
>>> zip(*data)
[(35, 35, 35), (35, 36, 38), (32, 33, 34)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
plot = zip(*[(x[0], x[1], x[2], voxelGrid[x]) for x in data])
```